# Why object property is not updating, React Hook with array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, object, react-hooks

I need to update a property of an object inside an array with useState
. But it don't update the quantity, where is the error?

( It is the initial state, i get all the rest of objects with axios from the
server )

```js
    const [data, setData] = useState([
      {
        codigo: 0,
        quantidadeAtual: 0,
        grptipo: "",
        grupo: 0,
        identificacao: "", 
        preco: ""
      }]);
```

```
function diminuirQuantidade(key: number) {
    setData(data.map(x => {
      let quantity = x.quantidadeAtual + 1;
      if (x.codigo !== key) return x
      return {...x, quantidadeAtual: quantity};
    }));
    }
```

```js
{data.map((data) => {
            // console.log(data.codigo);
            if (data.identificacao === "") {
            } else {
              data.quantidadeAtual = 0;
              return (
                <div className={estilos.subcontainer} key={data.codigo}>
                  <div>
                    <div>

                      <div>
                        <h1>{data.identificacao}</h1>
                      </div>

                      <div className={estilos.containerBotao}>
                        <button onClick={() =>
                       diminuirQuantidade(data.codigo)}>-</button>
                        <h2>{data.quantidadeAtual}</h2>
                        <button>+</button>
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div>
                      <h2>{data.preco}</h2>
                    </div>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
```

My data is like this:

```
[{ 
codigo: 308
grupo: 3
identificacao: "Água Mineral Com Gás"
preco: "R$ 3.50"
quantidadeAtual: 0
tipo: "Simples"
}, {...}]
```

I expected every time I click a button it decreases the quantity of one element.
It don't show any error message.

Comment: It would help if you posted more of your code - where the hook is defined, what is triggering this update, etc

Comment: Are you sure the `setData()` call is being executed? Add a `console.log()` in that map function. Does it run?

Comment: Just wanted to highlight that you mention to decrease the quantity but you are actually incrementing the quantity - `let quantity = x.quantidadeAtual + 1;`

Comment: @swapnesh I make it only for test, but thanks for the comment

Comment: @Tore I edited now with more code.

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes, it runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you set `data.quantidadeAtual` to `0` on render (in `data.map((data) => ...)`). This means that after pressing one of the buttons, you increment the quantity and then re-render (since state changed), which triggers the reset to 0. If you remove that line of code (and instead do that in an effect or wherever that logic belongs), it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Very thanks, it solved the problem, i missed that line of code there.